# How to change "Source" url on ROS Wiki for a package or stack?

Tags: ros, package, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like the Source url for a package I have on the ROS Wiki to point to a location other than the trunk.  For an example of what I mean, look at the [pr2_controllers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers) page where the Source url points to a branch rather than trunk.  Is this done using the [versioncontrol tag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest/XML#A.3Cversioncontrol.3E_tag) in the manifest.xml or stack.xml file or some other way?

Thanks,

patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10139/how-to-change-%22source%22-url-on-ros-wiki-for-a-package-or-stack?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The source URL is controlled by our indexer, not any property of the stack itself.

You can view the index at:

https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/rosorg/trunk/rosdoc_rosorg/repos.rosinstall

It can be updated by you contacting me with whatever adjustments you would like.

In the future, we hope to have version-specific URLs, which we would enable for 'released' stacks, but this will take time to implement.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-06-02**:
Thanks Ken--I'll leave it as is for now and adjust my svn organization accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The new way to do this is (post-electric) is documented here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Get%20Involved#Indexing_Your_.2A-ros-pkg_Repository_for_Documentation_Generation

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2